# Why does facebook api return invalid JSON (unquoted)

Tags: android, json, facebook

I'm trying to parse facebook graph api json response with Jackson json library on android.  But the json response has Unquoted json keys, ie:

```
{Response: responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":
```

I can get the json string with,

GraphObject o = response.getGraphObject();
JSONObject json = o.getInnerJSONObject();

but is there anyway to use with jackson?  I could parse the JSONObject string with jackson I guess, but that would be silly since I'm parsing the json string twice....

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? If you haven't already, consider updating to 3.5.

Comment: I'm using the latest version 3.5

Comment: Instead of doing your own parsing, you can actually create an interface that inherits from GraphObject, with getters/setters for your properties (e.g. "email" turns into getEmail), and use Response.getGraphObjectAs(YourInterface.class), and it will coerce the response into that interface. This is pretty similar to what jackson will do in terms of being strongly typed and having easy accessors. If you want to exercise the more advanced features of jackson, then you'll need to do what you're already doing.